# How to use regular expressions to find phrases, each of whose first letter is known?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find some movies from the imdb dataset (https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/). What if I know the first character in the name of every word of the title, but I don't know the actual title. So for example, I know that the first letters of each word in the title of the movie are A, M, A, T, W. This movie happens to be [Ant-Man and the Wasp](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5095030/?ref_=tt_sims_tt). I use the following regular expression to find the movie:

```
re.search('A[a-z]*M[a-z]*A[a-z]*T[a-z]*W', primaryTitle, re.IGNORECASE)
```

But the search does not bring back Ant-Man and the Wasp. These are my search results:

```
G�sgen - Ein Film �ber die Volksbewegung gegen Atomkraftwerke
Atomkraftwerk Kahl
Sthree Samathwam Olakkeda moodu
Tschingis Aitmatow - Schriftsteller
Dawid Podsiadlo: Malomiasteczkowy
YouTube's Akilah Hughes on #BlackWomenAtWork & Feeding the Buzz
Natsumi hinamatsuriwo mamore dearimasu/Keroro afuro demyaon dearimasu
Americatown
Welcome to Shamatown
Das Ding am Deich - Vom Widerstand gegen ein Atomkraftwerk
Americatown
Palomatown
Heimarbeit und Nebenverdienst/Automatenschwindelei/Nachlassschwindel/Experiment: Falschgeld
#andhiroshimaithoughtweweregoingtohavesomefun
BLACKMAGIC Cinema Camera (Diamaltwerke)
Travis Brasher and Ryan Ellis of TravisMathew
Diamantenwirbel
```

I have a tab opened with details of regular expressions, and I have looked at it over and over again, but I can't seem to identify how my regular expression is not working correctly.

Just for reference, this is my entire code:

```py
import csv
import re

with open('data.tsv', encoding='utf8') as titles:
    titleReader = csv.reader(titles, delimiter='\t')
    for title in titleReader:
        primaryTitle = title[2]
        if re.search('A[a-z]*M[a-z]*A[a-z]*T[a-z]*W', primaryTitle, re.IGNORECASE):
            print (primaryTitle)
```

Comment: Hint: which part of `A[a-z]*M[a-z]*` can match a hyphen? How about spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that example string, you can take into account that what comes after `A[a-z]*` can be either a space or a hyphen `[ -]` using another character class.

```
A[a-z]*[ -]M[a-z]*[ -]a[a-z]*[ -]t[a-z]*[ -]W[a-z]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xca2cW/1)